# RPi4 doesn't connect automatically to WiFi

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

##### Scenario

- Raspberry Pi 4
- Raspberry OS Lite (64 bit), bullseye
- Beside the integrated `wlan0` it has an external adapter `wlan1`
- My wlan network has been configured from Raspberry Pi Imager

Starting from a fresh install, the Pi connects to the wlan without any problems.

##### Problem

After I upgraded to the testing branch and I configured the `wlan0` as an AP, on the next reboot the Pi can't connect to the network using the `wlan1` interface.

The AP on `wlan0` is managed by `hostapd` and `dnsmasq`. It works flawlessly.

The interface `wlan1` seems to be up but not connected, as shown by `ip link`:

```
4: wlan1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:c0:ca:98:d8:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

If I manually run:

```bash
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
sudo dhclient wlan1
```

the Pi connects to the network, `ping 8.8.8.8` works but `ping google.com` does not:

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

It seems that there are problems with dhcp for `wlan1`. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: "After I upgraded to the testing branch" WHY? Are you testing the future software for any reason? Just restore from your backup.

Comment: I just like experimenting because I think it's the best way to learn. Before posting, I've tried whatever I was thinking. Thank you for your advice!